# Is this a valid moment generating function?

Tags: probability

A problem on an actuary exam said: "Assume $X$ is a random variable with moment generating function $M_X(t)=\frac{2}{(1-t)^4}$." Is this a valid moment generating function? Shouldn't we have $M_X(0)=\mathbb{E}[e^{0\cdot X}]=1$?

Comment: Yes. So it is not a valid MGF

Comment: I hope this was a practice exam and not an actual exam!

Comment: @Math1000 It was a practice exam published by Actex.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

A [basic property of the MGF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Important_properties) is $M(0)=1$, for the reason you wrote.

Hence, the given function is not a valid MGF.